# C# Exception logging ideas

Tags: c#, asp.net, logging, exception

I'm approaching the end of a C#/ASP.NET project I am developing, and I'll have to support this project among other C# projects for the foreseeable future. I really need a nice, simple  and global way to log all details of any exception that's been generated, and either email me/log to a database/etc, but also display a 'simple' version to the user.

What solutions are available for C# currently? Also, as my program is nearly finished without logging capabilities, it'd be great to somehow execute my logging code whenever an exception is thrown, without explicitly calling that.

Comment: you can quickly write your own , or you can use Microsoft ones..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/) from apache and logging block from best [practices and patterns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/practices/default) from microsoft.

If you have your custom exception, you can include the logging capabilities to it.

Comment: Probably a simple typo, but think you meant log4net

Answer (score 2):

Use Elmah. You can get it from NUGET. Log4net is also a good option.

Just add a Application_Error method to global.asax and handle your errors here.

Answer (score 0):

you could create a class that deals with all the logging and returns information that could be put in a simple messagebox that tells the user friendly idea and then just call your class method on a suspect bit of code. That is what I usually do.

alternatively this might help you if i was barking up the wrong tree(as does happen)

http://csharp-source.net/open-source/logging

Answer (score 0):

Consider [Windows Error Reporting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg487440.aspx). To use WER, just allow unexpected exceptions to escape your process. The OS will capture a snapshot and (with the user's permission) upload it to Microsoft's servers where it is automatically analyzed and (heuristically) placed into "buckets" (all reports in a single "bucket" have a good chance of being caused by the same bug).

This allows you to not only see the exceptions, but also collect snapshots of your process at the moment the exception was raised. VS2010 is capable of opening these snapshots (minidumps). WER also includes tools to determine which bugs are more important (i.e., affect more users).

You do need an Authenticode code signing certificate to use WER (prices have ranged from $100-$400 per year over the last few years).